# Ansible - Extracting a variable from a large JSON output

Tags: ansible

The **gcp_sql_instance_info** module does not seem to allow you to specify the name of the database you are trying to get info for. All it does is every detail of every database in that project.

What would be the best way to extract the "ipAddress" of a database *based on it's name* and register that value to a variable?

```
{
"resources": [
    {
        "kind": "sql#instance",
        "state": "RUNNABLE",
        "databaseVersion": "POSTGRES_13",
        "settings": {
            "authorizedGaeApplications": [],
            "tier": "db-custom-1-3840",
            "kind": "sql#settings",
            "availabilityType": "ZONAL",
            "pricingPlan": "PER_USE",
            "replicationType": "SYNCHRONOUS",
            "activationPolicy": "ALWAYS",
            "ipConfiguration": {
                "privateNetwork": "example-network",
                "authorizedNetworks": [],
                "ipv4Enabled": false
            },
            "locationPreference": {
                "zone": "us-west1-b",
                "kind": "sql#locationPreference"
            },
            "dataDiskType": "PD_SSD",
            "maintenanceWindow": {
                "kind": "sql#maintenanceWindow",
                "hour": 0,
                "day": 0
            },
            "backupConfiguration": {
                "startTime": "02:00",
                "kind": "sql#backupConfiguration",
                "backupRetentionSettings": {
                    "retentionUnit": "COUNT",
                    "retainedBackups": 7
                },
                "enabled": false,
                "replicationLogArchivingEnabled": false,
                "pointInTimeRecoveryEnabled": false,
                "transactionLogRetentionDays": 7
            },
            "settingsVersion": "3",
            "storageAutoResizeLimit": "0",
            "storageAutoResize": true,
            "dataDiskSizeGb": "100"
        },
        "ipAddresses": [
            {
                "type": "PRIVATE",
                "ipAddress": "10.10.10.1"
            }
        ],
        "instanceType": "CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE",
        "backendType": "SECOND_GEN",
        "name": "database-1",
        "region": "us-west1",
        "gceZone": "us-west1-b",
        "databaseInstalledVersion": "POSTGRES_13_7",
        "createTime": "2022-07-22T20:20:32.274Z"
    },
    {
        "kind": "sql#instance",
        "state": "RUNNABLE",
        "databaseVersion": "MYSQL_8_0",
        "settings": {
            "authorizedGaeApplications": [],
            "tier": "db-n1-standard-1",
            "kind": "sql#settings",
            "availabilityType": "ZONAL",
            "pricingPlan": "PER_USE",
            "replicationType": "SYNCHRONOUS",
            "activationPolicy": "ALWAYS",
            "ipConfiguration": {
                "privateNetwork": "example-network",
                "authorizedNetworks": [],
                "ipv4Enabled": false
            },
            "locationPreference": {
                "zone": "us-west1-c",
                "kind": "sql#locationPreference"
            },
            "dataDiskType": "PD_SSD",
            "backupConfiguration": {
                "startTime": "21:00",
                "kind": "sql#backupConfiguration",
                "backupRetentionSettings": {
                    "retentionUnit": "COUNT",
                    "retainedBackups": 7
                },
                "enabled": false,
                "transactionLogRetentionDays": 7
            },
            "settingsVersion": "1",
            "storageAutoResizeLimit": "0",
            "storageAutoResize": true,
            "dataDiskSizeGb": "10"
        },
        "ipAddresses": [
            {
                "type": "PRIVATE",
                "ipAddress": "10.10.10.2"
            }
        ],
        "instanceType": "CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE",
        "backendType": "SECOND_GEN",
        "name": "database-2",
        "region": "us-west1",
        "gceZone": "us-west1-c",
        "databaseInstalledVersion": "MYSQL_8_0_26",
        "createTime": "2022-07-27T19:27:59.235Z"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working playbook to achieve the desired output:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    db_instance_name: instance-1
  tasks:
    - name: get info on an instance
      gcp_sql_instance_info:
        project: project_id
        auth_kind: serviceaccount
        service_account_file: "/path/to/sa/example.json"
      register: cloud_sql_resources  
    
    - set_fact: 
        query: "resources[?contains(name,'{{ db_instance_name }}')].ipAddresses[].ipAddress"

    - set_fact: 
        ipAddress: "{{ cloud_sql_resources | to_json | from_json | json_query(query) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ipAddress }}"
```

You can run your playbook like this: `ansible-playbook -v main.yaml --extra-vars "db_instance_name=instance-1"`, that would print:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "35.224.46.127"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Extract the `ipAddress` of a database based on its `name`."***

A: Crete a dictionary. For example, select the first item from the list *ipAddresses*

```yaml
name_ip: "{{ dict(resources|json_query(name_ip_query)) }}"
name_ip_query: '[].[name, ipAddresses[0].ipAddress]'
```

give

```yaml
name_ip:
  database-1: 10.10.10.1
  database-2: 10.10.10.2
```

---

Notes

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - resources.yml
  vars:
    name_ip: "{{ dict(resources|json_query(name_ip_query)) }}"
    name_ip_query: '[].[name, ipAddresses[0].ipAddress]'
    name_ver: "{{ dict(resources|json_query(name_ver_query)) }}"
    name_ver_query: '[].[name, databaseVersion]'
    ip_of_db1: "{{ name_ip['database-1'] }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: name_ip
    - debug:
        var: name_ver
    - debug:
        var: ip_of_db1
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  name_ip:
    database-1: 10.10.10.1
    database-2: 10.10.10.2

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  name_ver:
    database-1: POSTGRES_13
    database-2: MYSQL_8_0

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ip_of_db1: 10.10.10.1
```

- There might be more IP addresses. The variable *ipAddresses* is a list. An option would be to create a list of all IP addresses. For example,

```yaml
name_ips: "{{ dict(resources|json_query(name_ips_query)) }}"
name_ips_query: '[].[name, ipAddresses[].ipAddress]'
```

give

```yaml
name_ips:
  database-1: [10.10.10.1]
  database-2: [10.10.10.2]
```